# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "IST"

Tags: java, parsing, date, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "IST" exception when i am trying to convert a String object into Date object. I tried to find the solution on the forum, but those were not helpful.

```
Date expiry=null;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

String actualDate;
if(!(actualDate=token.nextToken()).equals("null")){
    expiry = format.parse(actualDate);
}//if
```

Comment: What is *actualDate*?

Answer (score 2):

The string stored in `actualDate = token.nextToken()` is 'IST' which is not representing a date. Check the string source that you have tokenized to see, perhaps is not a date that is following in the token stream.